# i want upgrade my regex to let user write . or number but not alone and not write . in last of word

Tags: regex

I want to upgrade my regex to let user write `.` or number but not alone and not write `.` in last of word

Example:
I want to write

```
hello to web 2.0
```

or `hello farah.nor`

but not `hello word.`

and not `.....................` or `213123213123123`

Here is my regex

```
preg_match('#^[a-z0-9. ]+$#i',$text)
```

Comment: You've edited your question, so now a string of digits isn't legal anymore, either. What about a string of letters or spaces only? What exactly are the rules?

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there:

```
preg_match('#^[a-z0-9. ]+(?<!\.)$#i',$text)
```

The negative lookbehind makes sure that the string doesn't end in `.` (which it also does if it consists of `.` alone, so that condition is caught, too).

**EDIT:**

Now that you also want to disallow "digits only", you also need a lookahead assertion:

```
preg_match('#^(?![0-9]*$)[a-z0-9. ]+(?<!\.)$#i',$text)
```

Comment: thanx for help could tell me please good books or dvd tutorial learn regex

Comment: Try http://www.regular-expressions.info. It's free and very good. If you want to dig in deeper, check out the Regular Expressions Cookbook and Mastering Regular Expressions (both O'Reilly books).

Comment: Isn't it overkill to use negative lookbehind? `#^[a-z0-9. ]*[a-z0-9 ]$#i`

Comment: @xanatos: I wouldn't say overkill. Your version works fine, too. I find mine less repetitive. Probably a matter of taste.

Comment: @Tim My thought was "his is overkill, mine is repetitive, we live in a sad sad world" :-) :-)"

Comment: @xanatos: Cue Donnie Darko end montage soundtrack (although that's "Mad World", but close enough).